# Android: determine height of ActionBar Tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

does anyone no a way how I can determine the actual height of a Tab, using the ActionBar in "NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS".
I can determine the height of the ActionBar, but this does not include the Tabs height.
I can also determine the height of the icon (I am not using text, but this would also be possible if I would set a text on the Tab.

**But** it seems that there is some padding or margin around the content of the Tab and I am unable to extract this, therefore I can't determine the real height.

So can I somehow get this padding/margin or is there another solution to get the ActionBar-height plus the Tabs-height?

Answer (score 0):

You ma refer stackoverflow.com/a/9287224/1627599. I hope you will get some idea. Cheers!

Comment: This seems to be very strict and hardcoded.... the size of the icons inside the navigation-tabs is not strict it will be determined over the device screen size (hdpi, mpdi, ldpi, etc.) therefore it would look pretty ugly if I am using a fixed value for the tabs height.